# How to dynamically add items based on bound data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have ViewModel, and one of its fields contains array of objects. How can I create  `items: []` dynamically based on data of that field? Actually I need something like grid, but a bit more complex and with different layout. I guess I have to listen something like 'onChange' event for ViewModel, and do :

```js
this.add(Ext.create('MyItem', {data: ElementOfArrayFromVMField}))
```

Is this right way?

Comment: like `viewModel.bind('{arr}', this.createItems)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the way, which CD pointed, is the best. I extended Panel as Periods, and created method setPeriods. Then binding works perfectly. Most important thing - is the prefix 'set' in the metod, that named like bound field.

```
...
xtype: 'Periods',
bind: {
    periods: '{veiwmodel.periods}'
}
...
```

and inside Periods:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.Periods', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
...
setPeriods: function(items) {
    this.removeAll(true);
    this.add({...});
}
```